# Breaking a single lua function into small files

Tags: lua, code-cleanup, love2d

I'm working on a game using Lua and LÖVE.

I prefer a closure based approach to OOP and each level is a new instance of a function containing all the locals and functions needed to run the game.

I'd like to break this single function into multiple files. My current solution is similar to what I did here: [concatenating multiple files into a single one](https://github.com/OttoRobba/gel/blob/master/src/snippets/build_snippets.lua) - but I really don't think this is ideal yet.

For instance, I would have a load.lua file with the self.load function from the snippet below.

Code snippet of giant function for reference below:

```
levelSetup = function()
local time = 60
local timer = time
local timerIsRunning = true
local danger = 10
local handSize = 2
local itemsLeft = handSize
local curHand = 0
local lastHand = 10
local multiplier = 1
local self = {}

------------------------------------------------------
-- Initialize Values based on level Creation
------------------------------------------------------
self.load = function()
  if curLevel.time == 1 then
    time = 60
  elseif curLevel.time == 2 then
    time = 40
    multiplier = multiplier*1.5
  else
    time = 20
    multiplier = multiplier*2
  end

  if curLevel.danger == 1 then
    danger = 10 --low catastrophe chance
  elseif curLevel.danger == 2 then
    danger = 30 --medium chance
    multiplier = multiplier*1.5
  else
    danger = 50--high chance!
    multiplier = multiplier*2
  end

  if curLevel.handSize == 1 then
    handSize = 2
  elseif curLevel.handSize == 2 then
    handSize = 3
    multiplier = multiplier*1.5
  else
    handSize = 4
    multiplier = multiplier*2
  end
  itemsLeft = handSize
  timer = time
  self.nextHand()
end

  return self
end
```

#### What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function must be defined in a single chunk. However, using the [`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-load) function you can assemble your chunk data using multiple sources. E.g.:

```
function closuredef( ... )
  local modules, n = { ... }, select( "#", ... )
  local index = -1
  local function reader()
    index = index + 1
    if index == 0 then -- chunk prefix
      return "local self = {};"
    elseif index == n+1 then -- chunk suffix
      return "\nreturn self"
    else -- read specified Lua files and add them to the chunk data
      local modname = modules[ index ]
      if modname ~= nil then
        local fname = assert( package.searchpath( modname, package.path ) )
        local file = assert( io.open( fname, "r" ) )
        local data = assert( file:read( "*a" ), "could not read '"..fname.."'" )
        file:close()
        return data
      end
    end
  end
  return assert( load( reader, "=closuredef" ) )
end

levelSetup = closuredef( "level.variables", "level.load" )
```

This sample implementation uses [`package.searchpath`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath) (which is new in Lua 5.2) to make
specifying Lua files more convenient. If you still use Lua 5.1, you can use absolute file names or implement your own `package.searchpath` function. See [here](https://github.com/hishamhm/lua-compat-5.2/blob/032256051969f22dd2eae90fff130ad26d2efc96/compat52.lua#L443-L458), [here](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-amalg/blob/85940473c3f9a4f35e4175afecaea6293f12dc91/src/amalg.lua#L125-L143), or [here](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/62fc78dd0d4834619106797f8978ffdb302cb484/lua/pl/compat.lua#L125-L135) for samples.

I'm not sure this is the best solution for your problem though, e.g. you will have a hard time mapping line numbers in error messages to the real error locations ...

Comment: For this specific question, definitely the best answer - despite the debugging difficulty.

This "tough to clean" situation is probably saying that I need to rethink my code.

Answer (score 3):

It is always good to break your code into smaller files. If you are going to do that though, an elegant solution (in my humble opinion) would be using the `return` statement. This is a [very common and preferred practice](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide) in the Lua ecosystem.

Let us say your project consists of several **submodules**, respectively *submoduleA.lua*, *submoduleB.lua* and *submoduleC.lua*. Each of these submodules contains some specialized code (it can be a single function, or a set of functions, but let us assume we have a single function in each submodule).

Added to these submodules, you also have a **main file** (named *main.lua*) from which you want to call and use the functions defined in submodules.

*submoduleA.lua* would contain the definition for some function named *funcA*. This function can have its own locals, and use upvalues, no problem with that. Ideally, this *funcA* should be declared as a local inside the *submoduleA.lua* file, for scope issues. And then, at the end of the file, you use the `return` statement to return the function itself.

```
-- declaring upvalues, if any
local upvalue1 = ... -- placeholder code
local upvalue2 = ... -- placeholder code

-- function definition
local function funcA(arg1, arg2, ...)
  -- some code
end

return funcA -- at the end of the file
```

Same goes for *submoduleB.lua*, and *submoduleC.lua*

Then, in the *main.lua* file, you can easily call the functions defined in submodules using the [require](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/require) statement. Beware of one detail with `require`, you do not need to ad the extension name ".lua", as it automatically does it (the documentation is pretty explicit about this).

```
local funcA = require ('submoduleA') 
local funcB = require ('submoduleB')
local funcC = require ('submoduleC')
```

And that's it. Again, this is a very common pattern for Lua. I use similar technique when writing my own projects/librairies, especially when the code spans accross several files. See [Jumper](https://github.com/Yonaba/Jumper/tree/master/jumper) or [FloodFill](https://github.com/Yonaba/FloodFill), for reference.

I will also recommend those additional lectures for in-depth reflexion, as they pinpoint some very good policies to adopt when writing Lua modules:

- [How to write Lua modules](http://hisham.hm/2014/01/02/how-to-write-lua-modules-in-a-post-module-world/) (by Hisham M.)
- [How I write modules](http://blog.separateconcerns.com/2014-01-03-lua-module-policy.html), by P. Chapuis.
- [Guide to authoring Lua modules](http://kiki.to/blog/2014/03/31/rule-2-return-a-local-table), by E. Garcia Cota. This is a series of 4 posts, I just redirected you to the part 2, which is relevant here.

Hope this helps.